# grep two searched words

Tags: shell-script, grep

I could search lines that contain two specific words using the following in multiple files:

```
for f in $(ls *.txt); do
  echo ">"$f; more $f | grep word1 | grep word2
done
```

Now, I want to write a shell script to accomplish this so that I don't have to retype the whole thing again and again. I also wanted to add an option of using either one word or two words in the search.  I will be passing these searched word to the shell script at the command line.  I wrote the following shell script searchwords.sh:

```
word1=$1
word2=$2
for f in $(ls *.txt); do
echo ">"$f
###if word2 is empty; then execute 
if [-z $word2]; then
        more $f | grep $word1
else
###if word2 is not empty
        more $f | grep $word1 | grep $word2
fi
done
```

Usage:

```
sh searchwords.sh word1 word2
```

Although I got what I want, I am also getting an error ouput

```
[-z: not found
```

I know my code is not right, but I cannot place it.

Comment: You need a space after the `[`. Further, a) `ls *.txt` is broken (`for f in *.txt` will work), b) `more | grep` is a pretty bizarre way of giving `grep` some input.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your script:

- Missing space in `[-z $word2]`
- Missing double quote in variables
- Useless use of `more | grep`
- Parsing output of `ls` is broken
- `grep` will fail if `$word1` or `$word2` start with dash `-`

Here's a fix:

```
word1=$1
word2=$2

for f in ./*.txt; do
  printf '>%s\n' "$f"

  ###if word2 is empty; then execute 
  if [ -z "$word2" ]; then
    grep -- "$word1" "$f"
  else
  ###if word2 is not empty
    grep -- "$word1" "$f" | grep -- "$word2"
  fi
done
```